# New Vagrant Packaged Windows Server 2016 returning Authentication failure. Retrying

Tags: virtualbox, vagrant, windows-server-2016

I'm creating a base image using Windows Server 2016. The image is fully patched and has all the normal configuration applied, but when I test it, it fails to connect as the vagrant user, with a message that, from Google searches, implies it is trying to use SSH, although WinRM is listed in the dialog.

I've put my build documentation in [github](https://github.com/cdaf/windows/blob/master/vbox.md) for reference.

```
vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Importing base box 'WindowsDocker'...
==> default: Matching MAC address for NAT networking...
==> default: Setting the name of the VM: temp_default_1489982222856_48671
==> default: Clearing any previously set network interfaces...
==> default: Preparing network interfaces based on configuration...
    default: Adapter 1: nat
==> default: Forwarding ports...
    default: 5985 (guest) => 55985 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 5986 (guest) => 55986 (host) (adapter 1)
    default: 22 (guest) => 2222 (host) (adapter 1)
==> default: Booting VM...
==> default: Waiting for machine to boot. This may take a few minutes...
    default: WinRM address: 127.0.0.1:55985
    default: WinRM username: vagrant
    default: WinRM execution_time_limit: PT2H
    default: WinRM transport: negotiate
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
    default: Warning: Authentication failure. Retrying...
```

Note: Once the box is up, I can manually connect to is using WinRM?

```
$securePassword = ConvertTo-SecureString 'vagrant' -asplaintext -force
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential ('vagrant', $securePassword)
enter-pssession 127.0.0.1 -port 55985 -Auth CredSSP -credential $cred
[127.0.0.1]: PS C:\Users\vagrant\Documents> exit
```

Platform details

- Host is Windows 10
- Vagrant version is 1.9.2
- Oracle VirtualBox 5.1.18
- Guest is Windows Server 2016 Standard Evaluation

Note: In Vagrant 1.9.1, the guest gets destroyed instead...

```
    default: WinRM transport: negotiate
==> default: Forcing shutdown of VM...
==> default: Destroying VM and associated drives...
C:/HashiCorp/Vagrant/embedded/gems/gems/winrm-1.8.1/lib/winrm/http/response_handler.rb:57:in `raise_if_auth_error': WinRM::WinRMAuthorizationError (WinRM::WinRMAuthorizationError)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So it turns out I was not diabling User Account Controls (UAC), I've added the following to my worksheet.

```
reg add HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\System /v EnableLUA /d 0 /t REG_DWORD /f /reg:64
```